# Execute jQuery script in the correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chrome extension that consists of a html page and some .js scripts.

On my page I have a button,

**HTML**

```
<script src='api.js'></script>
<script src="jquery-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<button name="Log" type="submit" id="Log-submit">Save Result</button>
```

**api.js**

```
//  Add document to Elastic Search (Log)
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Log-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    $.ajax({
      data: JSON.stringify({ name: $( "div.Name" ).text(), xentime: entime, incident: "INC-"+ $("#incID").val(), team: $( "div.Team" ).text(), response: $("#option_id option:selected").text(), timestamp: $.now(), xuser: $("div.xuser").text(), xlocation: $("div.xloc").text()}),  //use variable value/text in JSON POST request
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: 'http://myapi.com:9200/escalations/escalation/'
    });
  });
});


// Close Window
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Log-submit").click(function() {
   window.close();
  });
});
```

When clicked it makes an API call to my elasticsearch index and populates with some JSON.

I then want the window to close.

At the minuet when I run it without the '`Close window`' my data populates but the window stays open.

If I run with '`Close Window`' my data doesn't populate but my window closes.

How can i get this to run in the correct order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing the window is cancelling the AJAX request. Do it in the success function of the AJAX request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Log-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
        btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    $.ajax({
      data: JSON.stringify({ name: $( "div.Name" ).text(), xentime: entime, incident: "INC-"+ $("#incID").val(), team: $( "div.Team" ).text(), response: $("#option_id option:selected").text(), timestamp: $.now(), xuser: $("div.xuser").text(), xlocation: $("div.xloc").text()}),  //use variable value/text in JSON POST request
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: 'http://myapi.com:9200/escalations/escalation/',
      success: function() {
        window.close();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I am getting the following error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' for line 'success: function() {'

Comment: Did you forget to add a comma to the end of the previous line?

Answer (score 1):

Your .ajax() call has a number of callback function you can provide in the configuration object, use window.close() in one of those functions.

Of note for your situation, there is "success" (as mentioned in the answer by @Barmar), "error" and "complete"

Answer (score 1):

Many times, a browser will abort pending AJAX calls and prevent new ones from executing if the browser is attempting to execute a close request such as `window.close();`. For this reason, add the `window.close();` statement into a promise callback of the AJAX call to allow it to complete first:

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify({ name: $( "div.Name" ).text(), xentime: entime, incident: "INC-"+ $("#incID").val(), team: $( "div.Team" ).text(), response: $("#option_id option:selected").text(), timestamp: $.now(), xuser: $("div.xuser").text(), xlocation: $("div.xloc").text()}),  //use variable value/text in JSON POST request
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://myapi.com:9200/escalations/escalation/'
}).always(function () {
    window.close();
});
```

You can use `.always()` if you want the `window` to close whether or not the AJAX call is successful. Likewise, if you want the `window` to close only after a successful response is returned, you can change `.always()` to `.done()`.

**Reference:** [`.always()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/), [`.done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)